# Python - How to bin float number when using pandas.plot.hist()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science, histogram

I am using Pandas and trying to create a histogram for the frequency of float numbers (in bins)

I don't need to set those myself to any special value, just get a reasonable looking histogram, showing the frequency of the data points in reasonable binning or continues axis.

Trying the use this code

```
vals, bins = np.histogram(total["ratio"].tolist(), bins=10)
total[["ratio"]].plot().hist(x="ratio", bins=bins)
```

I also tried using 10 as the parameter for bins. Got the same result

Taken [from the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html)

And still get the axis not binned, which creates a large mess.
[image: the result]
What am I missing here in order to bin the data?

Update

Using `df["ratio"].hist()` worked like a charm.
What was the reason that doing the actual same by `df[["ratio"]].plot().hist()` did not work?

Comment: For these data `total[["ratio"]].plot()` creates a messy line plot. Whatever you add after that command won't make it less messy.  Also note that you don't need `np.histogram()` if you're using `df["ratio"].hist()`.

Comment: to answer the question in your update: you don't need the `()` after `plot`. So, you either want `df[["ratio"]].plot.hist()` or `df[["ratio"]].hist()`, but not, `df[["ratio"]].plot().hist()`

Comment: Can either of you post an answer for me to accept?